# Matlab 10x10 random number buttons

Tags: matlab, button, random

I am trying to create a GUI figure with 100 push buttons, arranged in 10 rows and 10 columns. The numbers from 1 to 100 need to be randomly assigned to the buttons and displayed in white. However, I have no idea how to do this. What method should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this question is too broad.  There is no one method to do this, so I'll give you some pointers:

- You can create `uicontrol` objects, including buttons, using the [`uicontrol`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol.html) function.  Read the full description to see how to create buttons
- You can use the [`Position`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol_props.html#bqxoipv) property to set the button's position on the figure.
- You can use the [`String`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol_props.html#bqxoiqg) property to set the button's text
- You can use the [`ButtonDownFcn`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol_props.html#bqxoije) property to set a callback function which decides what to do when the button is pressed.

Hope that helps; try figuring out what to do from here and if you get stuck you can ask another more specific question.